# Why does tool bfg.jar remove files smaller as 1MB from Git with both options "--strip-blobs-bigger-than and --delete-files"?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I'm using both option `--strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M --delete-files '*.{jpg,png}'` together with bfg.jar tool. But some smaller as 1M files were deleted. Aren't these options working together ?

Answer (score 0):

These options do not constrain each other- they are additive in terms of the destruction they cause.

You probably just need the first option,  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M , to get the size savings you need. There is no option to constrain that to only working on files that are *.{jpg,png}